# Using INDIRECT and a cell reference to compare values on sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

Simple story - driving me cray cray.

I have a single Google Workbook with sheets within with separate names (`Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, etc).

I have a separate sheet called `Compare` that I want to make formulas for each cell such that I can check if there is a difference between the cells on different sheets.  For instance:

```
=IF(Sheet1!G4<>Sheet2!G4,Sheet1!G4&" | "&Sheet2!G4,"")
```

But I will use dropdowns on `L2` and `L3`, so now I would assume I could do:

```
=IF(indirect(L2&"!G4")<>indirect(L3&"!G4"),indirect(L2&"!G4")&" | "&indirect(L3&"!G4"),"")
```

in my comparison sheet on cell `G4`.

Problem is that this is ONLY for matching for cell `G4`.

How do I make the reference malleable so when I copy down, the ROW number changes, and when I copy right, the COLUMN reference changes?

I have tried to convert the cell reference into a text, but have not found a way to do it.

Any recommendations?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is a bit tricky to follow.  Please share a link to a sample workbook with the relevant formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(
    INDIRECT($L$2&"!R" & ROW() & "C" & COLUMN(),FALSE)
    <>
    INDRECT($L$3&"!R" & ROW() & "C" & COLUMN(), FALSE),

    INDIRECT($L$2&"!R" & ROW() & "C" & COLUMN(),FALSE) 
    & "|" & 
    INDRECT($L$3&"!R" & ROW() & "C" & COLUMN(), FALSE),
    
    "")
)
```

Using `"!R" & ROW() & "C" & COLUMN()` we use the R1C1 reference style. `INDIRECT` can use R1C1 by setting the second parameter to `FALSE`.

This does mean that you can only compare cells in two different cells with the same cell address. You can control this by making your own grid, with a column headers and row headers that you reference using lopsided absolute reference. `$A1` for rows and `A$1` for columns.

I suggest that you make a custom formula. It's a new feature that should have been rolled out for everyone by now. Go to Data > New Function > Add new function. Name it and give it a description. Argument names are `leftvalue` and `rightvalue`, though you can change that on your own disgression. the formula defintion goes:

```
IF(leftvalue <> rightvalue, leftvalue & "|" & rightvalue,"")
```

You can then add your descriptions and examples for each argument.

You can then write it more concisely as:

```
=COMPARE(
    INDIRECT($L$2 & "!R" & ROW() & "C" & COLUMN(),FALSE),
    INDRECT($L$3 &  "!R" & ROW() & "C" & COLUMN(),FALSE)
)
```

Comment: love this structure, I was not really looking for the actual R1C1 notation.  

I was assuming that when I put into a cell something like =A1 that when I copy it across, I get =B1; =C1; etc - and when I copy down I get =A2; =A3 and so on.

This method is incredible and will try it, but is there a simpler method?

Comment: But it WORKS!  Thanks David!

Comment: Glad to hear it works! I couldn't quite get a simpler solution, since dragging is important, but I just realized that maybe the `ADDRESS` function can help you. I'm not sure in what capacity, but it probably could.